# ClassCastException Parsing string to JSONArray

Tags: java, android, json

I have a JSON string like the one below being returned from a REST app to an Android app:

```
"{ \"error\" : false , \"volume\" : 1000 }"
```

I then try to parse out the response with following (not the exact function, but the exact code causing trouble):

```
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;

public void jsonFunction(String result){
    JSONArray jsonArr = (JSONArray) new JSONParser().parse(result);
    JSONObject json = (JSONObject) jsonArr.get(0);
}
```

However, every time I try to parse the JSON string, I get the following error:

```
java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.json.simple.JSONArray
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.json.simple.JSONArray
```

I've used the same code to parse a JSON response from another REST app within the same program, but that one executes without any trouble. If I try to parse directly to a JSONObject, I get a very similar error message. I figure there has to be something I'm not seeing, but for the life of me I can't quite seem to determine what it is.

EDIT:

This is what I get trying to parse directly to a JSON object:

```
java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.json.simple.JSONObject
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.json.simple.JSONObject
```

Comment: The error is clear: The given JSON is not an array.

Comment: Fortunately I have control over the source, but even when I take the original data object, place it into an array, and then send the stringified response, I still get the same error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your json response is not an array, this is all you need to do.

```
  import org.json.JSONException;
  import org.json.JSONObject;

  try {
       JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(result);
       boolean error = obj.getBoolean("error");
       int volume = obj.getInt("volume");
  } catch (JSONException e){

  }
```

Comment: org.json.simple apparently won't allow creating a JSON object in this fashion. It won't accept any parameters during the object declaration.

Comment: @MichaelMcCauley I just edited the answer to include the correct import of JSON you should be using.

Comment: Doing it this way, I get a similar error to above: Value {"error":false,"volume":1000} of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Comment: Your json is probably not formatted correctly. "{ \"error\" : false , \"volume\" : 1000 }" Can I ask why you have the quotes escaped here?

Comment: This is the app on the other end, stringifying the response object prior to responding to the REST call. Believe it or not, but the app is written in JavaScript, and is not running in a browser. This seems to be what the JavaScript JSON engine employed by this server does when stringifying an object.

Comment: So the actual response from the REST call contains those backslashes?

Comment: Yeah, it does. I'm wondering if maybe I need to go find some code to make my own JSON stringifier for the REST app so this will work correctly.

Comment: I don't know how your REST app is designed but you should just be able to return a json object without converting it to string. But to solve current problem, just add this above the try/catch. result = result.replaceAll("\\\\", "");

Comment: Ok, so I got an error with the replace method. For some reason the only value the object received was a left curly bracket. I altered the JS app to return the entire JSON object as opposed to its stringified representation, and... BOOM! It works! Thanks for pointing that out. Everything I've done with JSON prior required converting it to a string first before sending.